# Is "in resistance" like phrases "in trouble, in danger, in surprise, in grief"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

An incomplete sentence that I read in a dictionary:

> ...serving in resistance and partisan activities.

[Entry 2 of Partisan](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/partisan)

Does it mean:

> ...serving in resistance activivies and serving in partisan activities.

or "**in resistance**" is used as the same way as "**in troulbe**", "**in danger**", "**in surprise**", "**in grief**"?

Comment: @DialFrost Thank you for editing typos I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, we can (and often do) omit words for reasons of space or elegance (to avoid repetition that would be tedious for the reader or listener). This practice is called ellipsis. In your example, the noun 'activities' could have been placed after 'resistance' as well as after 'partisan'.

Suppose in one day, I milked my cow, played tennis, and attended my son's birthday party. I could say:

> Today I took part in farming activities, sporting activities, and
> family activities.

I could express this much more neatly by omitting all but the final 'activities':

> Today I took part in farming, sporting, and family activities.

[Ellipsis](https://www.thoughtco.com/ellipsis-grammar-and-rhetoric-1690640#:%7E:text=In%20grammar%20and%20rhetoric%2C%20an,words%20in%20a%20direct%20quote.)

Comment: One reason that I did not come up with ideas about ellipsis is that resistance is a noun instead of an adjective. Unlike words such as farming and sporting these good examples end with -ing. Suffix -ing is easily conneted with activities relating to farm and sport.

Comment: @StatsCruncher ellipsis can be used with nouns and noun phrases, as the page I linked to explains.

Comment: Do your mean "a word or group of words that function as a subject or object" on the linked page?

Comment: If so, the difficulty I had is with "a group of nouns". But now you shed light on that.

Comment: We use the noun _resistance_  in the sense 'secretly opposing the occupying power', which is evidently intended here. _Resisting_ wouldn't have the same meaning.